# Excel - How to convert hrs and mins stored as text into [h]:mm

Tags: excel, date-formatting

When I run a report and export to Excel, the hours and minutes are exported as a general text format.

So for example:

- 13 hours and 22 minutes is exported as `13.22`
- 0 hours and 33 minutes is exported as `0.33`

and so on.

The problem is, when I try to convert the data to the format `[h]:mm` which I need for data manipulation, they aren't converted correctly.

`13.22` is converted to `317:16` and in the formula bar displays `13/01/1900  05:16:48`

How would I convert `13.22` to `13:22` in the format `[h]:mm` so I'm able to manipulate the data?

Comment: Where are you exporting the data from, and do you have the ability to change the format of that information?

Comment: Hi Matt - I don't I'm afraid. It is very basic time management software and outputs things such as daily balance and running balance. There is nowhere where I can change the format. Cheers

Comment: how are you manipulating the data?  In excel or in some other application that reads from the excel file?

Comment: Well, for instance, I need to total what somebody has worked in a week. For example: Mon 9:10, Tues 8:00, Wed 8:28, Thurs 8:29, Fri 7:55 should equal 42:02 (42 hours and 2 minutes worked in the week)

Comment: yes, but are you doing it in excel?

Comment: ok, time is exported as 13.22 and this equals 13 hours and 22 minutes worked correct?... if so convert your fields to a float data type and add them together. Why convert it to time? Or is it that 13.22 is the time they clocked out and you need it converted to 1:22pm. Little confused as to what you are really trying to do. Your questions asks to have it converted to time but two comment fields about this you are just adding float values together - if it is just adding then CDbl(expression) is all you need

Comment: =VALUE(expression) is the formula to convert a string to its number representation.  CDbl(expression) is VBA side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you import data as 13.22 Excel interprets that as 13.22 **days** - changing format won't change that. If you can't change the import so that you import as 13:22 then you can try using a formula to convert, e.g. with 13.22 in A1 use this formula in B1

`=TEXT(A1*100,"00\:00")+0`

format B1 as [h]:mm

Comment: Nice.  I actually dug up a different way to do this, but yours seems a little more simple.